# Remove a file from Git repository, but stash it

Tags: git

I have some committed files in my Git repo that I'd like to remove from the index. However, I want to be able to quickly bring them back by putting them in a stash, so later I'd just be able to run, e.g., `git stash apply stash@{0}`. Is there some easy way to do this?

Comment: You could stash the files you've touched and don't want to commit, unstash them to a branch, then continue about your business on your main development branch instead.  Is this undesirable or inconvenient for you?

Comment: The files are already committed. I want to delete them from the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
git rm --cached file_you_want_to_remove
```

on each of the files you want to remove, then commit. This will delete them from the head of your branch but - since you specified `--cached` - will leave them in your work tree. (i.e. they'll still be visible on your local file system, but anyone pulling your commit from the repo won't see them.)

Next, use

```
git stash
```

to stash the files, like normal.